# Minimal polynom for $e^{2\pi i/3} + 2^{1/3}$

Tags: minimal-polynomials

I have $\alpha = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3}) + 2^{\frac13}$ and I need to find a minimal polynomial for It in $\mathbb Q$, the "obvious" Path is to get the third Power of each term, but I'm struggling with It
It would also be sufficient for me to show that $\mathbb Q(\alpha) = \mathbb Q(\exp(\frac{2\pi i}3))(2^{\frac13})$
But i dont even know If this is true

Comment: Call it a hunch, but I get the feeling that there's an $i$ missing from your expression. Can you confirm or deny this? :-)

Comment: Should that be $e^{2\pi i/3},$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes, Will fix It, Sorry guyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that
$$
\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/3}+\sqrt[3]{2})\subseteq
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})(e^{2\pi i/3})
$$
Note that
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})(e^{2\pi i/3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]=2
$$
because the degree of $e^{2\pi i/3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $2$ and $e^{2\pi i/3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Therefore the degree of $e^{2\pi i/3}+\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a divisor of $6$. Try and prove the degree is indeed $6$.

Let $\beta=e^{2\pi i/3}$, for simplicity. We have
$$
\sqrt[3]{2}=\alpha-\beta
$$
so $2=\alpha^3-3\alpha^2\beta+3\alpha\beta^2-\beta^3$. Since $\beta^3=1$, we have
$$
\alpha^3-3=3\alpha^2\beta-3\alpha\beta^2
$$
However, $\beta^2+\beta+1=0$, so we can write the identity as
$$
\alpha^3-3\alpha-3=\beta(3\alpha^2+3\alpha)
$$
Hence
$$
\beta=\frac{\alpha^3-3\alpha-3}{3\alpha^2+3\alpha}
$$
which yields, since $\beta^2+\beta+1=0$,
$$
\frac{(\alpha^3-3\alpha-3)^2}{(3\alpha^2+3\alpha)^2}
+\frac{\alpha^3-3\alpha-3}{3\alpha^2+3\alpha}
+1=0
$$
This can be written as a degree $6$ polynomial expression in $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

***Hint***

if $x=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}$

then cubing both sides gives

$$x^3=e^{2\pi i}+2+3\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$

$$x^3=e^{2\pi i}+2+3\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\left( x \right)$$

$$x^3-3=3\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} 2^{\frac{1}{3}} x$$

Cubing both sides

$$\left(x^3-3\right)^3=\left(3\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} 2^{\frac{1}{3}}x\right)^3 $$

$$\left(x^3-3\right)^3=-54x^3 \cdot$$

This is a polynomial which has $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ as one of its zero.
You might want to check if there is some other polynomial of smaller degree(obviously a factor of the above polynomial) which satisfies $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}$
If not, Then this is a minimal polynomial

Comment: Getting the minimal polynom, i get that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q] = 9$ does this mean that the base is {$1,\alpha,...,\alpha ^8$} ?

Comment: The degree is at most $6$. How can this be correct?